# Create dynamic table which can handle future changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, data-modeling, flexible-type

I try to create a database model which can handle future changes.

Short overview over my table relations:

tblProject -> (1:n) -> tblArticles

tblArticles -> (1:n) -> tblWorkingProcesses

tblWorkingProcesses -> (1:n) -> tblWorkingProcessesSteps

Currently I have 6 different working processes (wp), each wp has his own wp steps (12 tables). Each of the wp is different from the others, so I need separate tables. This solution is not flexible. In the future more wp's will need to be created. But I don't want create new tables every time when a new wp must be added.

What I am trying to do now is to create a more flexible model. I have a table named tblWorkingProcess. This table contains the parameters which appear in every wp (length, width, ... of a product).

Then I have a table tblWorkingProcessParameters which contains possible data types. Every row represents a data type. This rows of the table I want to use as additional columns for the table tblWorkingProcess. So every time when I add a column to the wp it's a new row in tblWorkingProcessParameters.

This same I want to do with the wp steps.

Currently it's just an idea for my model. Are there any problems with this solution? I am open for ideas for improvement.

Thanks.

Snapshot of my data model (only relevant tables):
https://i.imgsafe.org/36ca79c.png

Comment: You may want to read up on the EAV (entity-attribute-value) antipattern.

Comment: @reaanb gotta love the recommendation for an antipattern :-) Sql-server has an XML datatype that can be used instead of that antipattern

Comment: @ZoharPeled careful, readers may think that's a serious suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @reaanb. I was looking for something like this, but couldn't find while searching. I think this is a good solution for my problem, isn't it? Otherwise I have to create 2 new tables manually, when I want add a new working process.

Comment: @user3515431 Be sure you understand the problems and risks associated with that design before jumping in with both feet.

Comment: It would be really helpful to have some examples the working processes so we could see how they're different.  We may be able to see opportunities for abstraction that you've missed.  A polyglot solution could be very valuable here.  I agree with the comments that advise caution with EAV and XML.  SQL Server 2016 will support JSON, including index support, so that may be your best option.